# Get the the column value of a selected cell through .address vba

Tags: vba, loops, cell

I need to find a cell based on its value. Then I need to extract the value of a column from a
selected cell and use it in my loop to iterate through. When I try to use .address it gives me an error

```
 Set selectedCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Find("Start", LookIn:=xlValues)
 selectedCell.select
 Selection.Address

 While Not IsEmpty(Cells(3, EXTRACTED COLUMN VALUE HERE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selectedCell knows its column - no need to select it.
Like this:

```
Set selectedCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(3).Find("Start", LookIn:=xlValues)

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(3, selectedCell.Column))
```

Comment: Side note for OP: best to test if the `Find` succeeded: `If Not selectedCell Is Nothing Then`.